# Comment votes can be easily gamed by users with the association bonus

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, voting, deleted-accounts

When someone deletes an account, the upvotes they left on comments are not removed. When they create another account, they can upvote these comments once again.

This is a problem, as you can give a comment as many upvotes as you want by:

1. Upvoting the comment
2. Deleting your account
3. Repeating 1 and 2 ad infinitum

This can even be done very quickly, since upvoting a comment doesn't require you to contact SE to delete your account (the "Delete" button will remain in your profile settings).

Please wipe the comment votes when a user is deleted. Right now it is very easy for users with the +100 rep bonus to game the system and disrupt discussions.

Comment: To what end? They don't accrue any reputation. And how often do you think this is happening? How exactly is this a *"huge problem"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's not about accruing reputation, it practically ruins the point of comment upvoting. Users with a lot of upvotes can appear more genuine, so this can disrupt discussions. Unless, for some reason, you think allowing people to upvote comments infinitely many times can have a positive effect.

Comment: There's no need to add the "delete account" step in there.  Yes, anyone can create as many accounts as they want and use them to commit voting fraud.  It's against the rules, and that person would face serious consequences if they get caught.

Comment: I certainly do agree with S.C. *:: creates multiple accounts and upvotes his comment repeatedly ::*

Comment: @Servy How can someone possibly be caught? Does it not make more sense to preclude it entirely?

Comment: But *does it?* Do you have any evidence that people are creating multiple accounts (and earning 15 rep on each of them) just to repeatedly upvote comments? That seems wildly unlikely, even if it *did* matter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How *can* I have evidence? They will be anonymous. The problem is that, whether or not it's common, it has the potential to be very disruptive. Not to mention, users who have over 200 rep on one site can comment on any other site.

Comment: I'm not sure I see why this is a **huge problem** as you call it?  This would take a lot of effort by someone to vote on what is basically second-class content that could be deleted at any time.

Comment: @SirCumference I'm not sure anyone would *care* enough in the case of comment upvotes, because why would anyone even notice, but if someone abused it enough, or in a way that actually had a notable enough effect, someone might notice enough to care, at which point they're in pretty deep trouble.  As far as preventing it, one can trivially subvert your prevention technique by simply not deleting the accounts they keep creating.

Comment: Exactly my point; it's not at all clear where you've got the idea that this is happening. And now you're implying that people are creating multiple accounts and earning over 200 rep so they can do this across several sites?! Have you considered the more likely possibility that other people have different opinions on the value of a given comment to yours?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Are you serious? I never said this is happening to me. I said that this can potentially cause problems. Scroll up and re-read what I wrote.

Comment: Please explain how comment voting fraud leads to discussion disruption - I don't see the link. (never mind the point that you shouldn't be having discussions here - in comments or otherwise)

Comment: Potentially? We don't prevent potential problems - we fix/deal with **actual** problem as and when they arise.

Comment: You said *"This is a huge problem"* - if it's not happening, how is that the case? I disagree with your premise on multiple levels.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The problem is that the system can be easily gamed. You have no way of knowing whether it is happening or not — preventing it entirely would be the logical solution.

Comment: @Oded This may have *already* happened. You can't tell whether or not. Regardless, it's clear that users can cause a problem, and you will never truly know how big it is.

Comment: @SirCumference It can't be gamed *easily*, because it requires creating lots of accounts and getting all of them to have enough rep to vote on comments, which isn't easy, particularly without getting caught.  It's also not easily prevented, because if someone *does* take the time to do all of that then all they need to do to subvert your "prevention" is to not delete their accounts.

Comment: @Servy If someone has already received the +100 reputation bonus, it is incredibly easy.

Comment: I think some of you are missing the point of this post. OP has found a presumably unknown flaw to the system that allows egocentric and megalomaniac users validate themselves and disrupt the normal mechanics of standard discussions. I'm glad that most of you didn't have to deal with this kind of users, but let me tell you that they exist, and if something can be done to stand in their way and make it more difficult for them to do that, well, I think it should be done. It doesn't make sense not to. **Huge problem**, maybe not. Something for developers to bear in mind, IMHO, yes.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform - and yet, the issue is about **comments** which are not that important on the platform and which are considered ephemeral and subject to deletion at a moments notice. It talks about discussions, which as a rule we are **against** on the platform. It suggests disruption in a space where such suggested disruption is meaningless (I am yet to understand **what** form the disruption would take or, assuming it exists, why it is deemed problematic).

Comment: @Oded the worst that can happen is an arithmetic overflow on `comment.score` I guess?

Comment: @Oded Honest question: what's the purpose of comment upvotes if they're completely meaningless? Why do they exist? Right now, many users can upvote as many times as they want. Doesn't that destroy the point of them?

Comment: You tell me - what do **you** think the point of upvotes on comments is?

Comment: @Oded I'm not *declaring* a point for them. You claim that they are meaningless — you carry the burden of proof for that statement. All I'm saying is that they are broken.

Comment: Would my deleting this whole comment thread be proof enough for you?

Comment: @Oded You haven't addressed my question. *Why do they exist*? Surely they shouldn't be a feature if they have no purpose, right?

Comment: @SirCumference Comments exist to enable collaboration in making posts better. That's the official rationale: the reason they were implemented in the first place.

Comment: @dmckee I would prefer not to discuss this any further. The system can be abused, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Comments exist to supplement the post they are on - they are expected to be subsumed into it, at which point they lose their function and should be deleted (comments that do not supplement a post in such a way should be deleted) - unfortunately this doesn't happen nearly often enough. Voting on comments - is a way for the community to indicate importance/relevance of specific comments have in relation to the post they are on. That is all.

Comment: We are trying to explain to you that this "abuse" is minimal and meaningless. This is why we are not taking this seriously - you are yet to show an **actual** problem here.

Comment: In other words - the existence of a *theoretical* way to abuse a system, doesn't make such abuse possible *in practice*. We have seen no evidence of such abuse, and you have not shown us any cases of such abuse.

Comment: @Oded The problem is that there exists a feature (whether or not you consider it meaningless) that may well be broken. Is that not reason to fix it?

Comment: What would be the goal of such an abuser - and how would it cause problems on the site? Please, please, please explain to me this. Until I get it, the potential for abuse means nothing to me.

Comment: @Oded There's literally *no way* that I can show evidence. **That's not because a problem doesn't exist**, that's because comments are *anonymous*. The problem may be very common, but you wouldn't know. Fixing it just seems like a logical action.

Comment: Uh. Comments are not anonymous.

Comment: I am asking for something simple - you claim that the feature can be abused. I am asking you to explain the goal of such abuse - not the existence of not of such abuse. Explain to me **why** anyone would do this - to what end? And, assuming they succeed, the actual impact it would have on others.

Comment: @Oded I will not discuss this anymore. The problem exists — I would understand if you didn't consider it a top priority, but at this point you're arguing that we leave things the way they are. It doesn't make sense to me, but neither of us are getting anywhere.

Comment: @SirCumference If you care so much about something this stupid, there is a way to make SE fix it. It's very simple - just *exploit* this "bug" yourself! Get enough comments improperly upvoted that it *becomes* a problem. Then SE will care.

Comment: I too will stop discussing this. The completely theoretical nature of this form of abuse and the very low impact it would have on the system and its users means that it will indeed be left as is. We don't fix things that don't need fixing.

Comment: @Mysticial ...Are you joking? You're asking people to exploit this? It's one thing to be against fixing it, but it's another to encourage it.

Comment: @Mysticial ask nicael what happens in such case. (hint: word starting with "s", ending with "n")

Comment: @ShadowWizard That one was different. That bug *needed* to be fixed. This one doesn't.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - there was no need for nicael to exploit the bug in the first place. Sure, to show the issue - do it a few times to prove there is a problem. The excessive nature of the exploit is what earned nicael time in the penalty box.

Comment: I *really* don't get it. Are you people trying to argue that a comment with 40+ upvotes will have the same impact - credibility and visibility-wise - than one with no upvotes at all? That they are to all purposes equivalent? I know that in *theory*, they should be equivalent. But in *practice*, do you really think they are?

Comment: So, funny thing about this. The votes themselves *are* actually deleted. What we don't do, apparently, is update the denormalized `Score` stored on the comment itself. Regardless of whether or not this is a practical problem, we should probably do that if only for consistency's sake. Having said that, doing so has a caching implication in the API that I'm not sure how to handle off the top of my head (or if it's a real concern - I'm not familiar with that part of the code that much). Gonna have to think about it some.

Comment: In the meantime, y'all can demonstrate the severity of this issue by deleting your accounts to repeatedly upvote my comment above. ;)

Comment: so massively expanded count but no badge?

Comment: @Oded, you ask about why this should be considered a problem - please take a look at my two comments below Robert Cartaino's answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the votes are deleted, but the denormalized `Score` stored on the comment itself is not updated.

I spent some time looking into a fix and, after further discussion with Nick Craver, I have to be the bearer of bad news here - we can't fix it at this point. Not without spending a *lot* of effort on setting up special infrastructure to do so.

Here's why. Let's say we wanted to create a daily scheduled task that'd look over the comments and fix up the scores. This presents two common problems: race conditions due to our use of `READ UNCOMMITTED` and DB table locks due to sheer volume of data and ongoing queries, but let's say we work around the latter with batching and the former self-corrects on the next run...

The next and foremost problem is that the `Comments2Votes` table that tracks voting didn't always exist. This means that we can't simply look at the current number of recorded votes and update the scores. (This affects about 10,000,000 comments.)

We could try backfilling those "missing" votes, but they can't be mapped to any users that are still around *and* they'd effectively be a waste of storage for votes that will also never be able to be removed. We're talking millions of rows here.

And even if we were to get around this by excluding comments created before a certain date... first of all, that doesn't entirely help either since votes can be cast long after the comment was posted. Secondly, doing this would up the time for the update queries to run and further increase the chances that we lock up the DB.

So, fine. Why not just "unvote" the comments we know about when a user is deleted? User deletion runs in a transaction. This means we up the odds of hitting race conditions where someone is voting on a comment while a user's being deleted. This puts scores back out of sync and we're arguably worse off than where we started.

To be able to do this properly, we'd need to rework how user deletion works, get around the missing data issues, and queue up these normalizations somewhere where we could work through them without affecting the day-to-day operations on the site. It's a lot of work and a lot of complexity for something that has a minor benefit in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Easy fix: nuke those 10,000,000 comments. :)

Answer (score 12):

> 1. Upvote comment
> 2. Delete account
> 3. Repeat *ad infinitum*

Deleting an account is not a trivial task, so going through that process over and over for any perceived minor benefit would be really difficult to miss — assuming anyone would even bother at all.

Perhaps if there was more benefit to up-voting a comment, it might warrant additional protections. But this is the kind of hypothetical *problem* you might want to see demonstrated in actual practice before deeming it a problem at all.

Comment: inconsequential for you need not be inconsequential for everybody. For some users, comments (and upvotes thereof) *are* meaningful. Whether this is the official attitude towards comments or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform But no social system can be rendered 100% bulletproof, so you have to weigh the cost-benefits of plugging every highly unlikely scenario with a reasonable risk assessment that it will ever cause a problem at all.

Comment: But there *is* a significant benefit to upvoting a comment - support in one side of a discussion. This isn't some "minor" or "hypothetical problem" - how do you know it hasn't happened before, first of all? and second, since *discussing large changes is one of the best parts of stack exchange* it seems like this should be taken a heck of a lot more seriously.

Comment: @heather what significant benefit is there to a comment with upvotes?  I think your putting to much weight in a comment with upvote.  A comment is a temporary statement and it getting upvoted means nothing

Comment: @Ramhound, I've heard moderators say that on meta they look at comments to see what is being supported and what isn't, perhaps even more so than upvotes - I'd say that getting a comment upvoted doesn't mean "nothing". Also, I don't know about you, but I generally look at comment upvotes as support for an idea. For example - my comment's got four upvotes, so some people agree with me, but your comment has one, so some people agree with you too. Also, when there are a lot of comments on a post, the SE algorithm *sorts by upvote* - so clearly upvotes matter.

Comment: @heather The votes aren't entirely meaningless, that's true. But you can't read *too* much into them. Your comment has 4 votes. It's also a few hours older than Ramhound's. Does your comment have 4 times the support or did it just get seen by more people? Both? And I'm willing to bet money that none of the people who upvoted you deleted their accounts to do it again. :) What's identified here is a *potential* exploit, but not a very *probable* one, IMO.

Comment: @AdamLear, I'm merely responding to the idea that a comment with upvotes has no advantage over a comment without, which I must say is a preposterous idea IMO. As for the probability of it happening - who knows? I don't think we can say that it is high or low probability considering there's no evidence for either side =)

Comment: @AdamLear Well, is it likely to be fixed? :)

Answer (score 5):

While I agree this can be annoying and unfair, I don't think it justifies spending development time.

As others said, comment score has very small actual meaning: it does not affect reputation, and can give [a single silver badge at most](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/pundit).

There are ways to see comments with highest score, e.g. with SEDE, so if someone will spot comments with insane score (e.g. 100000), they can report it to the team, they will take a look and if needed punish the one gaming the system. "I was able to do that" is no excuse to game the system.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform If you delete your account, as suggested in this question, you can't get the badge anyway (and if you did, it'd be worthless, because the owner of the badge would no longer have an account), so I don't think it's a huge concern.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Good point, edited to mention this now.

Comment: @Aurora0001 they're talking about making others get the badge, from what I understand, which is indeed a concern. (small, but still)

Comment: That's true... Although I do wonder how many people are dedicated enough to create and delete their account many times to get someone else a silver badge (which ultimately is just a fun, yet meaningless, token). You're right though, I was only thinking of the risk of someone giving themselves a badge.